# Use session variable in PDO MSSQL Statement to get another column

Tags: php, sql-server, session, pdo

I'm trying to learn more about PHP, PDO and SQL and session variables. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I'm hoping to learn from what I'm attempting.

I'm grabbing a session variable that is an e-mail and want to use that variable in a PDO statement to grab a ID that is in the same table. Below is what I have so far. Thanks!

```
<?php
require_once ('PasswordVerifySession.php');

$dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=.database.windows.net;Database=';
$uname = '';
$pwd = '';
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$ticketNum = $_POST["txtTicket"];
$Email = $_SESSION["contEmail"]
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pwd, $options);
    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT contId FROM tblContestants WHERE Email = ????);
    $q->bindValue(':contId', $contID);
    $q->execute();
    $ContId = $q->fetch();
    $ContId = $ContId['contId'];
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
$error_message = $e->getMessage();
echo("<p>Database error: $error_message</p>");
exit();

}
```

?>

Comment: `session_start()` Where is it

Comment: Sorry it's there I didn't post the entire page. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take just a quick look at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
$Email = $_SESSION["contEmail"]
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pwd, $options);
    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT contId FROM tblContestants WHERE Email = :email");
    $q->bindValue(':email', $Email);
    $q->execute();
    $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $ContId = $row['contId'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once ('PasswordVerifySession.php');

$email = ...;//you obtain the email from somewhere

try{
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pwd, $options);
    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT contId FROM tblContestants WHERE Email = :email");
    $q->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $q->execute();
    $ContId = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $ContId = $ContId['contId'];
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo("<p>Database error: $error_message</p>");
    exit();
}  

?>
```